# Код сортировки марки, модели, года, пробега

Tags: javascript, php, json, сортировка

У меня есть дамп базы данных авто, он обновляется каждый час.  В ней находятся все значения  `auct_lots_xml_jp` Внутри нее есть столбик
`company_en` -**название компаний**
`model_name_en` -**название моделей**
`model_year_en` - **год выпуска**
`mileage_en` - **пробег**
Что мой код уже умеет:

В меню слева есть выбор марки авто, Toyota, например , потом страница перезагружается (каждый раз при выборе фильтра, это нужно через js и JSON делать.) Далее открывается список моделей, которые доступны для этой марки. Corolla, например, потом открывается года выпуска, когда эта модель была выпущена с 2000-2011, затем я выбираю год, и все фильтруется. На каждом этапе тоже фильтруется по модели и году.

```
 Вот код для вывод в  фильтр слева. <nav>
         <div class="dashboard-nav">
            <div class="dashboard-nav-list">
               <div class="dashboard-nav-item dashboard-nav-dropdown">
                  <a href="#!" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle">
                  Make & Model
                  </a>
                  <div class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-menu">
                     <ul>
                        <?php
                           // Retrieve the unique 'company_en' values
                           $query = "SELECT DISTINCT company_en FROM auct_lots_xml_jp ORDER BY company_en";
                           $get_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                           while ($company_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_query)) {
                               $company = $company_info['company_en'];
                               // Output a menu item for each company
                               echo '<li><a href="?company_en=' . $company . '">' . $company . '</a></li>';
                           }
                           ?>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dashboard-nav-item">
                  <a href="#" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item">Models</a>
                  <ul>
                     <?php
                        if (isset($_GET['company_en'])) {
                            $company_en = $_GET['company_en'];
                            // Retrieve the unique 'model_name_en' values for the selected 'company_en'
                            $query = "SELECT DISTINCT model_name_en FROM auct_lots_xml_jp WHERE company_en='$company_en' ORDER BY model_name_en";
                            $get_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                            while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_query)) {
                                // Output a list item for each unique 'model_name_en' value
                                echo '<li><a href="?company_en=' . $company_en . '&model_name_en=' . $info['model_name_en'] . '">' . $info['model_name_en'] . '</a></li>';
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="dashboard-nav-item">
                  <a href="#" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item">Year & Mileage</a>
                  <ul>
                     <?php
                        if (isset($_GET['company_en']) && isset($_GET['model_name_en'])) {
                            $company_en = $_GET['company_en'];
                            $model_name_en = $_GET['model_name_en'];
                            
                            // Retrieve the unique 'model_year_en' values for the selected 'company_en' and 'model_name_en'
                            $query = "SELECT DISTINCT model_year_en FROM auct_lots_xml_jp WHERE company_en='$company_en' AND model_name_en='$model_name_en' ORDER BY model_year_en";
                            $get_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                            while ($year_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_query)) {
                                // Output a list item for each unique 'model_year_en' value
                                echo '<li><a href="?company_en=' . $company_en . '&model_name_en=' . $model_name_en . '&model_year_en=' . $year_info['model_year_en'] . '">' . $year_info['model_year_en']. '</a></li>';
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <!--<div class="dashboard-nav-item">
                  <a href="#" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item">Mileage</a>
                  <ul>
                  // Пробег
                     <?php
                     if (isset($_GET['company_en']) && isset($_GET['model_name_en'])) {
                         $company_en = $_GET['company_en'];
                         $model_name_en = $_GET['model_name_en'];
                         $model_year_en = $_GET['model_year_en'];
                     
                         // Retrieve the unique 'mileage_en' values
                         $query = "SELECT DISTINCT mileage_en FROM auct_lots_xml_jp ORDER BY mileage_en";
                         $get_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                     
                         while ($mileage_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_query)) {
                             $mileage = $mileage_info['mileage_en'];
                             // Output a list item for each unique 'mileage_en' value
                             echo '<li><a href="?company_en=' . $company_en . '&model_name_en=' . $model_name_en . '&model_year_en=' . $model_year_en . '&mileage_en=' . $mileage_info['mileage_en'] . '">' . $mileage_info['mileage_en'] . '</a></li>';
                         }
                     }
                     ?>-->
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
         </div>
      </nav
```

Далее код самой сортировки:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row" id="car-infinite-list">
      <!--<svg id="banner">
         <path fill="none" stroke="#ceced6" d="M8 22.5H5C4.5 22.5 3.5 22.2 3.5 21C3.5 19.8 3.5 17.8333 3.5 17C3.5 16.5 3.9 15.4 5.5 15C7.1 14.6 10.5 13.8333 12 13.5L17.5 8C17.8333 7.5 19 6.5 21 6.5C23 6.5 31.5 6.5 35.5 6.5C36 6.5 37.2 6.8 38 8C38.8 9.2 40 11.1667 40.5 12L44 13.5C44.5 13.6667 45.5 14.3 45.5 15.5C45.5 16.7 45.5 20.6667 45.5 22.5H41" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
         <path fill="none" stroke="#ceced6" d="M16 22.5H33" stroke-width="2"></path>
         <circle fill="none" stroke="#ceced6" cx="12" cy="22" r="4" stroke-width="2"></circle>
         <circle fill="none" stroke="#ceced6" cx="37" cy="22" r="4" stroke-width="2"></circle>
         </svg>-->
      <?php
         if (!isset($model_name_en)) {
             // If model_name_en is not set, display all cars for the selected company_en and model_year_en (if set)
             if (isset($model_year_en)) {
                 $query = "SELECT * FROM `auct_lots_xml_jp` WHERE company_en = '$company_en' AND model_year_en = '$model_year_en' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 21";
             } else {
                 $query = "SELECT * FROM `auct_lots_xml_jp` WHERE company_en = '$company_en' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 21";
             }
         } else {
             // If model_name_en is set, display cars for the selected company_en, model_name_en, and model_year_en (if set)
             if (isset($model_year_en)) {
                 $query = "SELECT * FROM `auct_lots_xml_jp` WHERE company_en = '$company_en' AND model_name_en = '$model_name_en' AND model_year_en = '$model_year_en'  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 21";
             } else {
                 $query = "SELECT * FROM `auct_lots_xml_jp` WHERE company_en = '$company_en' AND model_name_en = '$model_name_en' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 21";
             }
         }
         
         $get_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
         $num_cars = $get_query->num_rows;
         
         if ($num_cars <= 0) {
             echo "No available products in this category yet.";
         } else {
             while ($get_list = mysqli_fetch_array($get_query)) {
                 // Display the car information
                 ?>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 kolbasa">
         <a href="damps_details.php?id=<?php echo $get_list['id'];?>&cate=<?php echo $get_list['company_en'];?>">
            <div class="thumbnail2"><img src="<?php echo $get_list['pictures']?>" alt=""/></div>
            <div class="kolbasa-title price">
               <h4><?php echo $get_list['company_en'] .' '. $get_list['model_name_en'] ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div>
               <div class="price1">
                  <span class="price1-sub">$</span>&nbsp;<?php echo $get_list['start_price_num']?>
                  <span style="float:right;font-size:initial">FOB Japan</span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="line">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
               <div class="desc"><?php echo $get_list['model_year_en']?>
                  <span style="float:right;"><?php echo $get_list['mileage_en']?></span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <?php
         }
         }
         ?>
      <!-- END PRODUCTS -->
   </div>
</div>
<br><br>
```

Вообще-то это все работает, но криво, хочется улучшить код сортировки
Хочется написать более чисто 4 if else для каждого: модель, год, пробег. Подскажите как это реализовать.
Спасибо.

```
var
if {} else {}
if {} else {}
if {} else {}
if {} else {}
if {} else {}
query  =
if (есть год) { $year_part = "AND". $year_en }
else {  $year_part = "" }
query = "SELECT * FROM auct_lots_xml_jp WHERE " . $year_part . $mileage_part
```

UPD Я немного обновил код уже почти приближен к тому , что хочу.

```
<?php
         if (!isset($model_name_en)) {
             // Если model_name_en не задано, отобразить все автомобили для выбранной company_en и model_year_en (если задано).
             if (isset($model_year_en)) {
                 $query = "SELECT * FROM `auct_lots_xml_jp` WHERE company_en = '$company_en' AND model_year_en = '$model_year_en' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 21";
             } else {
                 $query = "SELECT * FROM `auct_lots_xml_jp` WHERE company_en = '$company_en' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 21";
             }
         } else if (isset($model_year_en)) {
             // Если задано model_name_en и  model_year_en, отображаются автомобили для выбранной company_en, model_name_en и model_year_en
             $query = "SELECT * FROM `auct_lots_xml_jp` WHERE company_en = '$company_en' AND model_name_en = '$model_name_en' AND model_year_en = '$model_year_en'  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 21";
         } else if (isset($model_name_en)) {
             // Если задано model_name_en и не задан model_year_en, отображаются автомобили для выбранной company_en и  model_year_en
             $query = "SELECT * FROM `auct_lots_xml_jp` WHERE company_en = '$company_en' AND model_name_en = '$model_name_en' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 21";
         } else {
             // Если не заданы ни model_name_en, ни model_year_en, отобразите запрос по умолчанию
             $query = "SELECT * FROM `auct_lots_xml_jp` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 21";
         }
         
         $get_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
         $num_cars = $get_query->num_rows;
         
         if ($num_cars <= 0) {
             echo "No available products in this category yet.";
         } else {
             while ($get_list = mysqli_fetch_array($get_query)) {
                 // хочу тут показать все авто) хз как нужно сразу  можете сразу переходить к циклу while,
      ?>
```

Но все таки я прописывал откуда брать инфу для сортировки внутри  if else . ее можно вывести ниже?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `auct_lots_xml_jp` WHERE company_en = '$company_en' AND model_year_en = '$model_year_en' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 21";
```

ее же можно вывеси за if else как   тут в примере

```
query  =
if (есть год) { $year_part = "AND". $year_en }
else {  $year_part = "" }
query = "SELECT * FROM auct_lots_xml_jp WHERE " . $year_part . $mileage_part
```

UPD 2 Я еще подправил код ,

```
  <?php
       if (!isset($model_name_en)) {
   // Если model_name_en не задано, отобразить все автомобили для выбранной company_en и model_year_en (если задано).
   if (isset($model_year_en)) {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM `auct_lots_xml_jp` WHERE company_en = '$company_en' AND model_year_en = '$model_year_en' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 21";
   } else {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM `auct_lots_xml_jp` WHERE company_en = '$company_en' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 21";
   }
} else if (isset($model_year_en)) {
   // Если задано model_name_en и model_year_en, отображаются автомобили для выбранной company_en, model_name_en и model_year_en
   $query = "SELECT * FROM `auct_lots_xml_jp` WHERE company_en = '$company_en' AND model_name_en = '$model_name_en' AND model_year_en = '$model_year_en' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 21";
} else if (isset($model_name_en)) {
   // Если задано model_name_en и не задан model_year_en, отображаются автомобили для выбранной company_en и model_year_en
   $query = "SELECT * FROM `auct_lots_xml_jp` WHERE company_en = '$company_en' AND model_name_en = '$model_name_en' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 21";
} else {
   // Если не заданы ни model_name_en, ни model_year_en, отобразите запрос по умолчанию
   $query = "SELECT * FROM `auct_lots_xml_jp` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 21";
}

         
if (isset($_GET['mileage_en'])) {
   $mileage_en = $_GET['mileage_en'];
   if ($mileage_en == 999) {
      // Добавьте условие для отображения автомобилей с большим пробегом
      $query .= " AND mileage_en > 999";
   } else if ($mileage_en == 1) {
      // Добавьте условие для отображения автомобилей с маленьким пробегом
      $query .= " AND mileage_en <= 1";
   }
}
```

Comment: Для решения подобных задач существуют всякие построители запросов, например, https://github.com/envms/fluentpdo. Они позволяют удобнее собирать сложные запросы